# Can I track modified fields in MS CRM 2013?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I want to track modifications in CRM.
I.E. We create lead/opportunity, saved it. Now  I am updating several fields , again saved it. Again updating several field. So can I get those fields names which were modified after the creation?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Audit, you can find a tutorial here:

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmlessons/archive/2011/03/29/crm-2011-auditing-best-practices.aspx